# flutter add controller to an inputfield

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i have a inputfield in a a widget to get the user email, i need to add a controller to this, but if i add the controller: line then i get an error:

```
  child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new InputField(
              ****controller: emailController,******
                hintText: email,
                obscureText: false,
                textInputType: TextInputType.text,
                textStyle: loginFormTextStyle,
                textFieldColor: textFieldColor,
                icon: Icons.mail_outline,
                iconColor: Colors.blue,
                bottomMargin: 20.0,
                validateFunction: validations.validateEmail,
                onSaved: (String email) {
                  user.email = email;
                }),
```

how i can add the controller to this input without change the inputfield to a inputtextfield?

thanks

Comment: why you are not using TextField or TextFormField widget? it Gives you controller constructor for input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such kind of widget named InputField(). If you are expecting to take the user input's such as Username, password, mobile number etc. You need to use TextFormField, then you can get the controller parameter for your inputs. Check the below link

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html

It is having the explanation of how to deal with input validation. Please let me know, once you try this! Happy coding

Comment: Happy to help @ALEXANDERLOZANO If you need anything more don't hesitate to reach out to us. Happy coding